# What's the word for someone who has ownership and others can't copy or share with others

Tags: adjectives

I am looking for a word a friend used the other day to describe people who do not share easily. They need to be asked repeatedly not because its a secret but simply because they cannot or do not want to let it out with a particular person or generally.

Unfortunately, my friend and I cannot recall the word.

Comment: Do not share what? Possessions, thoughts, ideas?

Comment: This is a guessing game. Why don't you consult a thesaurus?

Comment: Maybe, taciturn or introvert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Reticent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reticent)***

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Not revealing one’s thoughts or feelings readily: she was extremely
>   reticent about her personal affairs

***[Laconic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/laconic)***

> (Of a person, speech, or style of writing) using very few words:

[***Aloof***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aloof)

> Not friendly or forthcoming; cool and distant:
>
> Conspicuously uninvolved:

Comment: Though reticent serves the purpose, but it still is not the exact work I was looking for. let me search for synonyms of reticent and share the word I was actually looking for.

But thanks a a lot :) this is probably the answer.

Comment: @Salik: _Reticent_ was given by Josh61 and you eliminated all the words he gave.

Comment: I see this answer was chosen. Which of the three words worked best in your mind @Salik?

Answer (score 4):

*[Reserved](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reserved) or reticent*,  may suggest the idea:

> - Given to or marked by self-restraint and reticence: a reserved person.

also *[secretive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/secretive) or tightlipped*:

> - not letting people see or know what you are doing or thinking.

(from TFD)

[Discreet](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/discreet) may be an expression close to what you seem to be looking for:

> - Possessed of, exercising, or showing prudence and self-restraint in speech and behavior; circumspect.

Comment: No,i know these.I didn't know that word.it wasn't about not letting people know anything at all. It was about not letting everyone know about things you are particular about.

Comment: Based upon the way the question was presented, the words presented by Josh61 would have been in my top six with taciturn.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean sharing personal thoughts and feelings...?

Introvert (or introverted) :

> - a person characterized by concern primarily with his or her own thoughts and feelings; a shy person

Recluse (or reclusive) :

> - a person who lives in seclusion or apart from society, often for religious meditation

From your comments (perhaps put this in the OP, as more explanation may be needed) :

> It was about not letting everyone know about things you are particular about.

Maybe the word you're looking for is more along the lines of *insecure* or *self-conscious*:

> - not confident or assured; uncertain and anxious

Comment: No,these are strong words compared to what I am looking for.but thanks :)

Comment: Edited, per your comments on @Josh61's post.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, **Discreet**, from Oxford online dictionary: discreet adjective (discreeter, discreetest) 1. Careful and circumspect in one’s speech or actions, especially in order to avoid causing offense or to gain an advantage: example ‘we made some discreet inquiries’

Comment: Sorry to waste space, just noticed that Josh61 already submitted this word.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest ***taciturn*** as you emphasized speech and wanted a less strong word. The term is close to *untalkative* and *uncommunicative* also but taciturn people are habitually silent and share little about themselves.

> (Of a person) reserved or uncommunicative in speech; saying little:
>
> [[OD]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/taciturn)